# How do I earn the most XP per kill (in single-player)?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In single-player, extra XP is earned by killing enemies in special ways. I've been trying to only kill with arrow headshots. Does this method of killing earn the most XP per kill?

I originally phrased the question as "how do I earn the most XP (in single-player)". If there is some way to earn XP that makes juicing XP from kills a waste of effort, I'd like to know too.

Comment: Dont quote me on this but I believe stealth kills give the most xp per kills. I seem to remember playing TR with a rather Dishonored style of play.